# Odoo how to create or update record using XML

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I have read Odoo documentation for creating new record. It uses XML RPC.

```
final Integer id = (Integer)models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
db, uid, password,
"res.partner", "create",
asList(new HashMap() {{ put("name", "New Partner"); }})
));
```

So is it possible to create new record only using XML message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. here is the [documenttation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html)

and here is an example to create customer record using just a python file.

```
import xmlrpclib

username = 'admin' #the user
pwd = 'admin'      #the password of the user
dbname = 'odoo'    #the database

# Get the uid
sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)

#replace localhost with the address of the server
sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')

partner = {
   'name': 'atul arvind',
   'phone': '8000111234'
}

partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)
```

It will return newly created record's id.

hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. But I want to use plain XML message as I am not using any programming language. So what will be the XML message for inserting or updating records? Thanks.

Comment: without any programing language ?

Comment: what you want to develop ?

Comment: Hi, actually I am integrating Odoo with other ERP where I can use XML messages to add or update master data in Odoo from other ERP system. So what will be sample XML message to insert or update record in the Odoo?